# Extracting data from MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with a simply MySQL query. Query A returns results but Query B does not.

Query A:

```
Select Count FROM scur_shoutcast_playlist WHERE Artist = "Migos"
```

Query B:

```
Select Count FROM scur_shoutcast_playlist WHERE Title = "Clarity"
```

===

I know for sure that my database has a song with the title "Clarity" within the Title column. Anytime I try and pull data based on the title it won't return but everything else works. I have posted the table structure below

ID :: ARTIST :: TITLE :: UPLOADED :: PLAYED :: GENRE :: VOTES :: GRADE :: COUNT :: EMAIL

I am trying to display the Count for a specific song based on it's Title. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Also, The column 'Title' is set to unique if that helps.

Comment: Note that while `count` is not reserved, it is a keyword and so best practice suggests that it should not be used as a table/column identifier.

Comment: any errors from mysql?

Comment: looks like either Clarity spelled differently in the database or it is in different case try UPPER(Title) = "CLARITY"

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
Select Count FROM scur_shoutcast_playlist WHERE Title like "Clarity"

                               Or
Select Count FROM scur_shoutcast_playlist WHERE Title like "%Clarity%"  

                               Or 
Select Count FROM scur_shoutcast_playlist WHERE lower(Title) like lower("clarity")
```

Comment: I was able to get this working! Thanks! The Title field was adding a space in front of the string which could only be seen when you manually edit the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also :

```
SELECT `Count` 
FROM scur_shoutcast_playlist 
WHERE lower(Title) like '%clarity%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.. I found the solution.

When viewing my table via phpMyAdmin and looking at the Title column everything looked normal so I decided to edit an entry and when doing so I noticed that a "SPACE" has been added to the beginning of each title as in " Title" but you can only see this when you edit the entry. Very strange.